# Compiling Bower Components in a Rails app using Gulp

Tags: compilation, gulp, assets

I have my Rails app set up with a set of Gulp tasks which compile my app assets and vendor assets (both styles and scripts) together and output them appropriately in the `public` directory. This is all great but it does mean that when assets such as images etc are linked to from a components js or css file that it cannot be found as the main files have been compiled.

I've looked around at a variety of solutions but nothing seems to match up to what I am after or I can't seem to get them to work.

Ideally (I think) I would like to find out what images etc are being requested by the components and move them into the appropriate place within my `public/assets` directory and then update the references to reflect that.

I am posting my full Gulp file below so you can see what I have so far but any help on how I would go about doing the above would be ever so grateful!

```
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var sass          = require('gulp-sass');
var concat        = require('gulp-concat');
var rename        = require('gulp-rename');
var util          = require('gulp-util');
var postcss       = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer  = require('autoprefixer');
var cssnano       = require('cssnano');
var svgstore      = require('gulp-svgstore');
var svgmin        = require('gulp-svgmin');
var path          = require('path');
var replace       = require('gulp-replace');


// ===============================================================

var is_production = !(util.env.dev);

// ===============================================================

var vendor_styles = [
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/flickity/dist/flickity.css',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/animate.css/animate.css',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
];

var vendor_scripts = [
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/jquery-ujs/src/rails.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/jquery-backstretch/jquery.backstretch.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.min.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/drop/drop.min.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/uri.js/src/URI.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/svg4everybody/dist/svg4everybody.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/css-element-queries/src/ResizeSensor.js',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js',
  './vendor/assets/markermanager.js',
  './vendor/assets/jquery-throttle-debounce.js'
];

// ===============================================================

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  var postcss_tools = [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 3 versions']
    })
  ];

  if (is_production) {
    postcss_tools.push(cssnano());
  }

  gulp.src('./app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.{sass,scss}')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}))
    .pipe(rename('application.css'))
    .pipe(postcss(postcss_tools))
    .pipe(replace(/(url\(\.\.\/|\.\.\/)/i, '../bower_components/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/stylesheets'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src('./app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('application.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/javascripts'))
});

gulp.task('vendor_styles', function() {
  gulp.src(vendor_styles)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/stylesheets'))
});

gulp.task('vendor_scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(vendor_scripts)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/javascripts'))
});

gulp.task('svgs', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/assets/svgs/**/*.svg')
    .pipe(svgmin(function getOptions (file) {
      var prefix = path.basename(file.relative, path.extname(file.relative));
      return {
        plugins: [{
          cleanupIDs: {
            prefix: prefix + '-',
            minify: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }))
    .pipe(svgstore())
    .pipe(rename('application.svg'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/svgs'));
});

// ===============================================================

gulp.task('watch', ['styles', 'scripts', 'vendor_styles', 'vendor_scripts', 'svgs'], function() {
  gulp.watch('./app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('./app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('./app/assets/svgs/**/*.svg', ['svgs']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: This is clearly not a Rails project.

Comment: What makes you say that?  It is a Rails app actually

Answer (score 0):

URL modification is unneeded if you copy referenced assets into correct relative paths.

#### Example

Let's say you have a bower component called componentA with a `styleA.css` that references `logoA.jpg`:

```
.logo {
   background-image: url('./img/logoA.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}
```

Stucture of this module would look like this:

```
bower_comonents/
\_ componentA/
  \_ styleA.css
  \_ img/
    \_ logoA.jpg
```

Compilation produces `application.css` in `public/` folder. This file contains reference to `logoA.jpg` (`./img/logoA.jpg`). In order for this reference to work, `logoA.jpg` needs to be copied into correct relative path,
so that compiled structure would be as following:

```
public/
\_ application.css
\_ img/
  \_ logoA.jpg
```

#### Solution

I would suggest to do the same thing that you're doing with JavaScript and CSS sources. Just list them in a variable and copy into `public` in a separate gulp task.

Something like:

```
var vendor_assets = [
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/flickity/dist/images/flickity.jpg',
  './vendor/assets/bower-components/leaflet/dist/images/leaflet.png',
];

gulp.task('vendor_assets', function() {
  gulp.src(vendor_assets)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/'))
});
```

Comment: Its not that I'm stuck with. It's how to alter all the references in the files themselves to the assets location that I'm having issues with.

Comment: Yes, but it's not needed if you copy referenced assets into correct relative paths. I will augument my answer.